# adding widget dynamically python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have these two python scripts that I want combine into one window. Basically, adding the widget to the window when the button is checked. 
this is the main window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 171, 21))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        // when checkbox is true add widget

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "render frame range"))
```

this is the widget that I want  to add

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 120, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 120, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 131, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "to"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Render Sequence"))
```

I know I need to parent the widget to the main window but I don't know how. When the checked box is true I want the widget to be added. If the check box is false I want the widget to be deleted. I've seen examples with c++ but not python.  If someone can help me or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add/delete the widget. You can just hide or show it according to the state of your checkbox.

Connect the signal `QCheckBox::clicked` to the slot `QWidget::setVisible`:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.checkBox = QCheckBox("Hide/show", self)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 171, 21))

        self.widgetToManage = QLabel("Hello world!", self)
        self.widgetToManage.hide() # the checkbox is unchecked by default.

        # When the checkbox is checked, the widget is visible.
        self.checkBox.clicked.connect(self.widgetToManage.setVisible)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    app.setActiveWindow(window) 
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: TypeError: setVisible() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: I got it to work with show instead setVisible                                                      self.viewport2RenderChBox.clicked.connect(self.widgetToManage.show)